# Ubuntu - PostgreSQL failing with no error message

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, start

I've installed PostgreSQL 9.0 on Ubuntu 10.04 using **[this](http://www.dctrwatson.com/2010/09/installing-postgresql-9-0-on-ubuntu-10-04/)** guide.

However, when I try to start the service, I get this back, with no error or message shown.

```
root@srv1:/etc/init.d# ./postgresql start
* Starting PostgreSQL 9.0 database server
* The     PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output.
                                                                     [fail]
```

I don't know where the log file is to see this error. It's definitely not in /var/log/* or /var/log/postgresql

Comment: Can you check your postgresql.conf file and look for the logging options? I see PG output logs in /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-8.4-main.log and I've left my logging options at default on Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Weird! I looked into the config file and found all logging was disabled. I turned on logging and now the service starts ok!!! - THANKS!

Comment: ahh.. it was to do with rights of the log file.. :(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was to do with not having write access to the log file for the 'postgres' user.

IMO, the startup script should echo an error to the screen instead of telling you to check the log that it can't even write to.